# How to bundle CSS from master and individual views in .NET Core?

Tags: css, .net-core, bundling-and-minification

I have the following in the project.

```
_Layout.cshtml - Master page
  <environment names="Development">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
  </environment>
  <environment names="Staging,Production">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" />
  </environment>

Page1.cshtml   - uses Master page
  <environment names="Development">
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/page1.css">
  </environment>
  <environment names="Staging,Production">
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/page1.min.css">
  </environment>        

About.cshtml   - uses Master page
  <!-- no styles specific to the page -->
```

I am trying to create a bundle to serve css as a single file.  So in bundleconfig.json I have the following:

```
{
  "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
  "inputFiles": [
    "wwwroot/css/site.css"
  ]
},
{
  "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/page1.bundled.min.css",
  "inputFiles": [
    "wwwroot/css/site.css",
    "wwwroot/css/page1.css"
  ]
}
```

So when I server Page1.cshtml, I changed my style declaration to the following:

```
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/page1.bundled.min.css">
</environment>
```

And About.cshtml just relies on the single site.min.css file from the master page.

However, in this case Page1.cshtml ends up serving both site.min.css (from master page) and page1.bundled.min.css (which already includes site.css).  This is obviously wrong.

So what is the correct method of bundling files from the master and individual pages?  Do I pull out all styles from the master page and just serve the page specific bundles directly from individual views?  It kind of defeats the purpose of having a master page.

P.S. I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010001/what-are-the-mechanics-of-producing-bundled-js-and-css-files-with-master-pages) previously, but I didn't explain the problem correctly.

Comment: "*Page1.cshtml ends up serving both site.min.css (from master page) and page1.bundled.min.css (which already includes site.css). This is obviously wrong.*". I disagree - this is expected behaviour. Your `layout` (master page) should include content (and CSS rules) that you want to apply to **every** page, with your page-specific rules only applying to the page in question. If there's conflict, the individual page's rules should have more specificity in order to overwrite the rules from the master layout.

Comment: @ObsidianAge The problem is that I already bundled site.css with page1.css into page1.bundled.min.css (see my bundleconfig.json).  Therefore, having master page spit out site.min.css and then having the page1.cshtml view spit out page1.bundled.min.css will result in duplicate css in the browser.